# What order should experiences appear in a coverletter?

Tags: job-search, cover-letter

In cover letters what order should experiences (for example work you did in previous jobs) be discussed? Chronological, reverse chronological or by order of relevance?

I'm applying to a job right now that is at a start-up company, and I have worked for a start-up before though it was not my most recent job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your letter should focus on the most obvious and most significant need, and offer support for, at most, the two next most priorities. If you're filling a position for ecommerce, and the last ecommerce work you did was 5 years ago, that goes first, even if you're really proud of the Crystal Reports migration you've been doing for the last 18 months. Similarly, if you worked in Electronic Medical Records two years ago, and Visual Basic in the job you currently have, an employer maintaining EMR systems is more interested in that background than the VB, even though they also use VB.

Comment: So what you're trying to say is most relevant experiences go first?

Comment: Most relevant to them. What did they ask for in their job posting, and what kind of hints did they drop in any phone conversations? If you know people working there and know what they're looking for, that should be the first thing they see in the letter.

Comment: What a messy resume that will be

Comment: @Horus, the question is asking about the cover letter -- not the resume. These two documents are very different in content and purpose. I would certainly not advocate swapping around the order on a resume!

Comment: @jmac - my mistake

Comment: My resumes are tightly focused on user needs, and put the highest need first. I would also do that in the cover letter, but I don't normally write cover letters.

Answer (score 1):

They should always be listed in order of relevance.

The average recruiter or maanger will not have time to read each resume in detail. At best, they will skip over it. Each resume gets a quick 5-10 second scan. If the manager thinks it's not useful, your resume gets put on the reject pile, even if you are the best person for the job.

So be short, and be highly relevant. As long as you don't lie, it doesn't matter when the experience was. If the recruiter has any questions, they will ask you in the telephone/screening interview. But for that, they must have first read through your resume first, and for that you need a highly relevant resume.